# Sheet relationship that changes it's value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

I’m currently creating an bigger excel sheet as a storage management tool. To be precise, it’s an hobby project I just wanted to start doing. I worked all Saturday night to do it, but I’m stuck really badly and I can’t figure out how to solve this one problem!

I have two lists:

- Material Overview – this is an overview of all the material and it’s total quantity
- Log – this is the log, where I can enter if we sold material or bought material

But now that’s where it gets tricky:

I want the log sheet to automatically change the material overview depending on how you entered the forms. I attached some screenshots as an example:

**This is the log-File. It logs the changes done to the quantity of the product.**

[image: This is the log-File. It logs the changes done to the quantity of the product.]

**This is the material overview. This should change to 1 now considering we entered +1 in the log sheet.**

[image: This is the material overview. This should change to 1 now considering we entered +1 in the log sheet.]

I have no idea how I have to implement this. Also, there are multiple Articles on the material overview and the log sheet that can be changed.
Could you please help me out on this matter? Would be really nice.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I suggest you remove the `Typ` column in the Log table and use `+1` or `-1` to represent an increase or decrease in quantity. In your master sheet, if your product's default opening quantity is not zero, you should have a column for the starting quantity, and in another column, use the **SUMIFS** formula to obtain the movement of quantity for each product, and then have a third column to show the ending quantity. If all your products' opening quantity is zero, then you can use the **SUMIFS** formula in Column `Amount` to calculate the on-going quantity per product. Try google **SUMIFS**.